# How to enforce reads from read replica in Postgres using django and or flask?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is enforcement of a reads from a read replica an application layer task?

i.e. I have a Postgres database and I have set up a read replica.

On the application side I have two connections one for the "write" database and one for the "read replica" database.

In my code if I do a "read" action I use the connection to the read replica. But when I go to insert or update I use the connection to the "write" database a.k.a. master.

Is there better with django or flask that this is managed automatically. i.e.

I would prefer to avoid specifying directly in code the connection to use and just have django or flask figure it out on their own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Django**

For this purpose django supports so called Database routers.

First create your custom router:

```
class CustomRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'replica'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'master'
```

And configure django orm to use it like that.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'primary': {
        'NAME': 'master',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'spam',
    },
    'replica1': {
        'NAME': 'replica',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'eggs',
    },

}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.CustomRouter']
```

The sample code was taken from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) (it is worth reading!) and slightly adjusted.

**SQLAlchemy (flask)**

I went through the SQLAlchemy docs and found a link to [this article](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/), which describes how to implement djangos database router approach with SQLAlchemy.

You can use a custom session here to implement this properly.

The following snippets are picked from the linked article and are slightly adjusted.

Create your engines:

```
engines = {
    'master': create_engine('postgresql://user:***@localhost:5432/master',
                            logging_name='master'),
    'replica': create_engine('postgresql://user:***@localhost:5432/replica',
                             logging_name='replica'),
}
```

Create a custom session class:

```
class RoutingSession(Session):

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        if self._flushing:
            return engines['master']
        else:
            return engines['replica']
```

And create your session like this:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(class_=RoutingSession, autocommit=True))
```

Read the article for details and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

here is concept solution for flask witch change

```
"""This is not the full code. We do a lot of stuff to clean up connections, particularly for unit testing."""
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query, Session, scoped_session, sessionmaker

CONFIG_KEY_SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'
CONFIG_KEY_SQLALCHEMY_RO_BINDS = 'SQLALCHEMY_READ_ONLY_BINDS'

class Config:
    # These default values are for testing. In a deployed environment, they would be three separate instances.
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://localhost/branded_dev'
    SQLALCHEMY_READ_ONLY_BINDS = {
        'replica': 'postgresql://localhost/branded_dev',
        'replica_analytics': 'postgresql://localhost/branded_dev'
    }

class DBSessionFactory:
    """
    A wrapper for getting db sessions from the primary and read replicas.
    """
    def register(config):
        self.engines = dict()  # type: Dict[str, Engine]
        self.read_only_engines = defaultdict(list)  # type: Dict[str, Engine]
        # The session factories to be used by scoped_session to connect
        self.session_factories = dict()  # Dict[str, sessionmaker]
        # The scoped sessions for each connection.
        self.scoped_sessions = dict()  # Dict[str, scoped_session]
        # The scoped sessions for each read only connection.
        self.read_only_scoped_sessions = defaultdict(list)  # Dict[str, List[scoped_session]]

        # The primary connection
        self.add_engine(
            'primary', config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, config=config
        )
        
        # Other read-write dbs
        for name, connect_url in config[CONFIG_KEY_SQLALCHEMY_BINDS].items():
            self.add_engine(name, connect_url, config=config)
        # Read replica binds
        for name, connect_url in config[CONFIG_KEY_SQLALCHEMY_RO_BINDS].items():
            self.add_engine(name, connect_url, config=config, read_only=True)
    
    def add_engine(self, name: DBInstance, uri: str, config: Config, read_only=False) -> None:
        """Initialize a database connection and register it in the appropriate internal dicts."""
        # Clean up existing engine if present
        if self.engines.get(name) or self.read_only_engines.get(name):
            self.session_factories[name].close_all()

        engines = [self._create_engine(u, config) for u in uri] if isinstance(uri, list) \
            else [self._create_engine(uri, config)]
        for engine in engines:
            self.session_factories[name] = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)

            scoped_session_instance = scoped_session(self.session_factories[name])
            if read_only:
                self.read_only_engines[name].append(engine)
                self.read_only_scoped_sessions[name].append(scoped_session_instance)
            else:
                self.engines[name] = engine
                self.scoped_sessions[name] = scoped_session_instance
                
    def _create_engine(self, url: str, config: Config):  # pylint: disable=no-self-use
        """wrapper to set up our connections"""
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            url,
            pool_size=config.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE,
            pool_recycle=config.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE,
            echo=config.SQLALCHEMY_ECHO,
            pool_pre_ping=config.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_PRE_PING
        )

    @contextmanager
    def session(self, engine: DBInstance=None) -> Generator[scoped_session, None, None]:
        """
        Generate a session and yield it out.
        After resuming, commit, unless an exception happens,
        in which case we roll back.
        :param engine: connection to use
        :return: a generator for a scoped session
        """
        session = self.raw_scoped_session(engine)
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.remove()
    
    def read_only_session(self, engine: str=None) -> scoped_session:
        """
        Return a session for a read-only db
        :param engine: connection to use
        :return: a Session via scoped_session
        """
        if engine in self.read_only_engines:
            return random.choice(self.read_only_scoped_sessions[engine])
        else:
            raise DBConfigurationException(
                "Requested session for '{}', which is not bound in this app. Try: [{}]".
                format(engine, ','.join(self.read_only_engines.keys()))
            )


# The global db factory instance.
db = DBSessionFactory()
```

https://gist.github.com/jasonwalkeryung/5133383d66782461cdc3b4607ae35d98